# Crossing multiple entities in EasyAdmin 3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I've got a 3 entities and I would like to get property from entity 1 to entity 3. Let me explain with my classes :

```php
class City
{
  #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 1)]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 20)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private string $code;

#[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: CityHomePage::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private CityHomePage $homePage;

 public function getHomePage(): CityHomePage
    {
        return $this->homePage;
    }

    public function setHomePage(CityHomePage $homePage): self
    {
        $this->homePage = $homePage;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
class CityHomePage
{
  #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: City::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private City $city;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Page::class, inversedBy: 'cityHomePages')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private Page $page;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Image::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Image $image;

    public function getCity(): ?City
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(City $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPage(): ?Page
    {
        return $this->page;
    }

    public function setPage(?Page $page): self
    {
        $this->page = $page;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): Image
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(Image $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
class Page
{
  #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 100)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 1)]
    private string $title;

    /** @var Collection<int, CityHomePage> */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'page', targetEntity: CityHomePage::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $cityHomePages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->cityHomePages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    
    /**
     * @return Collection<int, CityHomePage>
     */
    public function getCityHomePages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cityHomePages;
    }

    public function addCityHomePage(CityHomePage $cityHomePage): self
    {
        if (!$this->cityHomePage->contains($cityHomePage)) {
            $this->cityHomePage[] = $cityHomePage;
            $cityHomePage->setPage($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCityHomePage(CityHomePage $cityHomePage): self
    {
        if ($this->cityHomePage->removeElement($cityHomePage) && $cityHomePage->getPage() === $this) {
            $cityHomePage->setPage(null);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I created a CityCrudController and in my configurationField I add :

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('name',$this->translator->trans('EA.name'))->onlyOnIndex(),
            TextField::new('code')->onlyOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('homePage', $this->translator->trans('EA.image'))->onlyWhenUpdating(),

        ];
    }
```

This is work but now I need to access from my CityCrudController the property 'title' from the Entity Page.
Is it a way to cross multiple entity to get what I need ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found it => 'city.page.title'